# Continue text underneath image in Latex

Tags: pdftex

I want to insert an image in Latex, but the text in my document should continue underneath the image (see inserted image). The image should not be completely "underwritten", only to a certain point should be text, and then the text continue below the image.
It that somehow possible? E.g. to make a part of the image transparent for the text?
Thanks for any advice!

[image: img]

Comment: Would semitransparent text on top of the image also be OK?

Comment: I would like to have a continuous text. Unfortunately, it is not possible to do a separate text window for that task...

Comment: Please clarify if the text can also be on top of the image instead of behind.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is written to the pdf file after the picture and at the same position, it will be written over it. The main problem is to lay it at the proper position.

The simplest solution is to use tikz in order to create overlays (zero size images), but other means exist certainly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{monalisa}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}
    {\LARGE \textbf{mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa
        mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

[image]